# Bring component to front when clicked/interacted with

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am currently working on a bit of a "free-drag" website (similar to operating systems) and I have got things draggable, and componentized them, however I am struggling when it comes to bringing a clicked-component to the front (and above anything else)

I have tried using z-index, however I'm not sure how id make it globally accessible and apply to only one at a time, right now they all count up from 1 individually when clicked and so, if I click one 3 times, I have to click the other 4 to get it on top.

Here is the array of objects, that render my components and the #each block

```
let windowCards = [
    { windowtitle: 'about.txt', contenttype: 'about', xpos: -500, ypos: -70, },
    { windowtitle: 'about.txt', contenttype: 'about', xpos: -300, ypos: -20,},
    { windowtitle: 'testing.txt', contenttype: 'about-alt', xpos: -100, ypos: 0, }
];
{#each windowCards as card}
        <WindowCard
            windowtitle={card.windowtitle}
            contenttype={card.contenttype}
            xpos={card.xpos}
            ypos={card.ypos}
            
        />
    {/each}
```

And then here is the component it is rendering

```
<div
    class="os-card one"
    style="z-index: {zIndex} !important"
    use:draggable={{
        bounds: 'body',
        handle: '.os-card-bar',
        defaultPosition: { x: xpos, y: ypos }
    }}
    on:neodrag:start={() => increaseZ()}
>content-here</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Dispatch a custom event](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte#createeventdispatcher) or forward `on:neodrag:start` (remove the handler, [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#on-eventname))
- Handle the event in the parent to update all z-indexes
- Possibly pass index into the component if that should be managed internally

With forwarding the structure would be something like this:

```html
<script>
  let windowCards = [{ ..., z: 0 }, { ..., z: 1 }, ...];

  function bringToFront(card) {
    // Could do:
    // - Copy items
    // - Remove `card` from argument
    // - Sort by z
    // - Add `card` to end
    // - Iterate list and set card.z to index in list
  }
</script>

{#each windowCards as card}
    <WindowCard
        windowtitle={card.windowtitle}
        contenttype={card.contenttype}
        xpos={card.xpos}
        ypos={card.ypos}
        z={card.z}
        on:neodrag:start={() => bringToFront(card)}
    />
{/each}
```

Note, that if you mess with the ordering of the original list it can cause issues if the `#each` is not keyed, see [docs](https://svelte.dev/docs/logic-blocks#each).

You might also be able to fix order by actually just doing that: Use a key and sort the original list to move the items in the DOM hierarchy (if these are actual DOM elements).

Comment: sorry i must have missed this!

I added "(window.id)" to my #each - seems to solve my issue!

I ended up using the array to order the cards (by render) rather than manually changing Z-index via CSS.

Unless there would be an issue doing it this way I may run in to down the line?

Comment: In general I would avoid messing with the z-index anyway, it makes things more complicated. Cannot think of any particular issue this might cause either.