# Having an issue with UI order & Arrays

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

im trying to imitate a desktop/os window, where clicking one item/window brings it to the top of the stack.

I previously used a ".isactive" method, but this didn't get the stack-effect I was looking for.

So, I instead moved my items to an array, and figured whichever item was on bottom would appear on top, and if I could bring the clicked-window to the bottom of the array, it would show on top, and so on.

I got the logic working, however the content just swaps place, rather than the card-order.

[Here is a quick video](https://share.cleanshot.com/wthH0XNl) showing what I have right now. What I am trying to do, is get the card "Two Two" to move to the bottom of the array, and so then show as "on top".

However, what happens, is the array updates, and instead the content shifts place.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
  let windows = [
    { id: 1, title: "one", content: "two" },
    { id: 2, title: "two", content: "two" },
    { id: 3, title: "three", content: "two" },
  ];

  function moveToBottom(index) {
    const clickedWindow = windows[index];
    windows.splice(index, 1);
    windows = [...windows, clickedWindow];
    console.log(windows, index);
  }

    {#each windows as window, index}
      <div
        use:draggable={{
          bounds: "body",
          cancel: ".no-drag",
        }}
        class="window"
      >
        <button class="no-drag" on:click={() => moveToBottom(index)}>Move To Bottom</button>
        {window.title}
        {window.content}
        <button on:click={() => removeItem(index)}>Remove This Tab</button>
      </div>
    {/each}
```

I'm also open to any other/better ways of managing windows/order. As I mentioned the class-approach worked but it wouldn't keep the stack-order it would just bring to front, or back to its original index.

Quick-edit: I also get a [similar issue when removing items from the array](https://share.cleanshot.com/Z886YGbH). As if the last-array item moves to the next. So, rather than "One One" getting removed, it removes it form the array, and all the others move up one. Rather than just removing the "One One" window.

Comment: I don't know why the fixation about manipulating an array for something purely visual. If you need to keep an X,Y,**Z**,W,H for your windows... simply modify the `Z` and apply it to the CSS `z-index`. You could also use CSS variables and style.setProperty() in JS. Also, why use an array? An Object (or Map) can give you direct access to the data instead of uselessly iterating arrays.  `const windows = {2: {}, 99: {}, 45: {}}` Want to delete the window 99? No need to iterate. Want to access its data? No need to iterate. Etc etc

Comment: I already explained [in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118369/bring-component-to-front-when-clicked-interacted-with) that you need a key in the `#each` when you change the order/do anything besides appeding.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i guess i was defaulting to array as im not overly sure how i'd create a new object/window onto the screen at the click of a button and pass in all the info needed? Im quite new to most of this so array just felt like the most obvious/easiest but if there is a better way I'm more then maybe you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Consider removing this question. There are already many variations of this, all having the answer "add a key".

Answer (score 0):

I think making a new array would solve the problem. I.e pushing the clicked window into that new array. That way the last-clicked-window would on the bottom.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).